# Oracle - start job when database starts

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling

I would like to schedule a plsql procedure to run every time the Oracle database gets started up. The procedure will execute an infinite loop that retrieves data via a REST interface from a remote server every 30 seconds and inserts it into a local database table. `DBMS_SCHEDULER` however does not seem to support this scenario, since it wants to run the job at a specified interval.

I don't want another job every 30 seconds, since the first job will be running in an infinite loop. Then I will have millions of jobs running in an infinite loop. Also I subtract the time the REST API takes to complete from the 30 seconds, so that I can call the restrictive REST API precisely every 30 seconds.

Also sometimes the REST API takes longer than 30 seconds to complete so then I just want to call again when it completes. All this to prevent getting throttled.

How can I schedule a job so that it starts every time the database gets started, so that it will always run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just schedule it to run every 30 seconds. When the database is down, of course that nothing will happen. But, as soon as it is up, scheduler will take over and execute that job as scheduled.

---

It seems that I misunderstood the question - you want to run **one job** at startup, and it'll run in an infinite loop. It was "30 seconds" that confused me.

Anyway: create a database trigger which fires on database startup, and let it schedule that job. For example:

```
create or replace trigger trg_schedule_job
  after startup on database
begin
  dbms_scheduler.run_job('schedule_job');
end;
/
```

Comment: I don't want another job every 30 seconds, since the first job will be running in an infinite loop. Then I will have millions of jobs running in an infinite loop. Also I subtract the time the REST API takes to complete from the 30 seconds, so that I can call the restrictive REST API precisely every 30 seconds.

Comment: Also sometimes the REST API takes longer than 30 seconds to complete so then I just want to call again when it completes. All this to prevent getting throttled.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question. In that case, a trigger might help. I edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: The better way is just schedule the job at 30 second intervals and let it complete normally. But if you really need an infinite looping job then look into the data type "interval day to second" - to calculate the necessary time interval to the next iteration - and the Oracle supplied package [Dbms_Session](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/dbms_session-sleep-18c).